# What happens when an Azure App Service restarts?

Tags: azure, restart, azure-web-app-service

What is happening behind the scenes when an App Service is restarted?

I'm trying to troubleshoot a slow restart for my app (ASP.Net and Sql published from Visual Studio) and I feel like understanding this would help me know what the issue is. My app starts within a few seconds on my dev machine but takes 90 seconds on Azure.

From my research, it sounds like a new service instance is provisioned, application files are copied from the shared storage to the instance and it is started. Is this correct? Is there a way to monitor the startup process to see what is slow?

Edit:
It's a tier S1 service plan. The app isn't slow, just the restart. I was hoping to understand the process so that I could understand whether the slow startup is due to my code or just the nature of the way the restart works. I've noticed that my app runs for about 10 seconds after the restart (refreshing the page), then I get a service unavailable for about 20 seconds, then the page is loading until for about 60 seconds.

Answer (score -2):

It all depends which app service plan you are using, different plans have a different memory, network bandwidth, IO etc, App Service runs customer apps in a multi-tenant hosting environment. Apps deployed in the Free and Shared tiers run in worker processes on shared virtual machines, while apps deployed in the Standard and Premium tiers run on the virtual machine(s) dedicated specifically for the apps associated with a single customer.
Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation) for a guide on Troubleshooting slow WebApp in Azure.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  If it depends on which App Service Plan is in use, could you explain what the differences are between each one?  Also, the OP asked specifically about restarts, but the information here refers to a link on slow performance in general, which doesn't seem relevant.